# Select current date by default in ASP.Net Calendar control

Tags: asp.net, calendar

Let's say I have an aspx page with this calendar control:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  SelectedDate="" ></asp:Calendar>
```

Is there anything I can put in for SelectedDate to make it use the current date by default, without having to use the code-behind?

Comment: New answers showing code behind examples miss the point and will be downvoted. You have been warned.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are already doing databinding:

```
<asp:Calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server"  SelectedDate="<%# DateTime.Today %>" />
```

Will do it.  This does require that somewhere you are doing a Page.DataBind() call (or a databind call on a parent control).   If you are not doing that and you absolutely do not want any codebehind on the page, then you'll have to create a usercontrol that contains a calendar control and sets its selecteddate.

Comment: Thank you, Page.DataBind() was the thing I was missing.  I've got that in my web page base class now and it's all good.

Answer (score 16):

**DateTime.Now** will not work, use **DateTime.Today** instead.

Comment: Old now, but this missed the point: those expressions both depend on having C#/VB code somewhere. This page should not have any of that type of code. Was going for markup only.

Answer (score 7):

I was trying to make the calendar selects a date by default and highlights it for the user.
However, i tried using all the options above but i only managed to set the calendar's selected date.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    Calendar1.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
}
```

the previous code did NOT highlight the selection, although it set the SelectedDate to today.

However, to select and highlight the following code will work properly.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
    Calendar1.TodaysDate = today;
    Calendar1.SelectedDate = Calendar1.TodaysDate;
}
```

check this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k0f6h1h(v=VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 6):

Two ways of doing it.

### **Late binding**

```
<asp:Calendar ID="planning" runat="server" SelectedDate="<%# DateTime.Now %>"></asp:Calendar>
```

### Code behind way (Page_Load solution)

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindCalendar();
}

private void BindCalendar()
{
    planning.SelectedDate = DateTime.Today;
}
```

Altough, I strongly recommend to do it from a BindMyStuff way. Single entry point easier to debug. But since you seems to know your game, you're all set.

Comment: Unfortunately, this a very simple page and there's no other databinding anywhere.  In fact, if I can get this working the way I want there won't even a code-behind.

Answer (score 4):

I have tried above with above code but not working ,Here is solution to set current date selected in asp.net calendar control

```
dtpStartDate.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.Date);
dtpStartDate.VisibleDate = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToString());
```

Comment: You missed the point of the question: no C# allowed. ASPX markup only.

Comment: A technicality because his answer is actually the only correct one because DateTime.Now does not work.  It has to be DateTime.Now.Date in order for the control to actually select the date.  So the "correct" answer is SelectedDate="<%# DateTime.Now.Date %>"

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem in VWD 2010 and, by chance, I had two  controls. One was available in code behind and one wasn't accessible. I thought that the order of statements in the controls was causing the issue. I put 'runat' before 'SelectedDate' and that seemed to fix it. When I put 'runat' after 'SelectedDate' it still worked!
Unfortunately, I now don't know why it didn't work and haven't got the original that didn't work.

These now all work:-

```
<asp:Calendar ID="calDateFrom" SelectedDate="08/02/2011" SelectionMode="Day" runat="server"></asp:Calendar>
<asp:Calendar runat="server" SelectionMode="Day" SelectedDate="08/15/2011 12:00:00 AM" ID="Calendar1" VisibleDate="08/03/2011 12:00:00 AM"></asp:Calendar>
<asp:Calendar SelectionMode="Day" SelectedDate="08/31/2011 12:00:00 AM" runat="server" ID="calDateTo"></asp:Calendar>
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I cannot get selected date in aspx. Here is the way to set selected date in codes:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
   {
      DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
      Calendar1.VisibleDate = dt;
      Calendar1.SelectedDate = dt;
      Calendar1.TodaysDate = dt;
      ...
    }
 }
```

In above example, I need to set the default selected date to yesterday. The key point is to set TodayDate.  Otherwise, the selected calendar date is always today.

Comment: Thanks for the "visibleDate". I know how to set selectedDate but no how to show on the Calendar!!!